# I'm being held against my will on a Jetty (server)!

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, services, webserver

I'm running Linux Mint 18.2. For some strange reason, systemd is spawning a Java process running jetty, on localhost:8080. Browsing there, I get the default "Welcome to Jetty 8 on Debian" static page.

So, I've done `update-rc.d -f jetty8 remove`, and I guess that will make the problem go away, but - I'm sure I never asked jetty to be installed, and surely not to be loaded by default. What's the reason for that happening?

Comment: Services are enabled and started at install time on Debian and derivatives.  `aptitude why <package>` will show whether the package is a dependency of some other currently installed package or not.  This is more comprehensive than the information you get with `apt-get remove <package>` as it will also point to "Recommends" deps.  (I think `aptitude remove` will as well, not that I'm suggesting it).

Comment: `i A libjetty8-java Suggests jetty8` - is that it? And apparently a bunch of Eclipse stuff depends on libjetty8-java.

Comment: Nope.  `Suggests` doesn't get installed automatically.  This says to me that  aptitude didn't find any stronger dependency on `jetty8`, by any currently installed package.

Comment: @sourcejedi: It's a mystery then...

Comment: Use `apt-get remove` (since there are no direct Recommends) and maybe you'll notice if it happens again :).

Comment: @sourcejedi: Already have.